# Installing the egg file of enum34

Tags: enums, easy-install, arcpy, egg

I am trying to install enum34 so that I can use the dbf module for arcpy. I downloaded dbf, but enum34 is a requirement. I am using ArcPython 2.7.

I downloaded the enum34 zip file - enum34-1.1.6.zip (md5) - from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34. Then, I basically followed the instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddpYVA-7wq4 and used Command Prompt. The install appeared to be successful and within my python27 folder in the site-packages folder, there is a enum34==1.1.6-py2.7.egg file. I then tried to import enum34 in Command Prompt, but I am receiving the error:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named enum34
```

I downloaded easy_install by running this code - http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py - in IDLE. I received this:

```
Setuptools version 0.6c11 or greater has been installed.
(Run "ez_setup.py -U setuptools" to reinstall or upgrade.)
>>>
```

Then, I ran with no problems:

```
import easy_install
```

Then, I tried to run in IDLE and in Command Prompt:

```
easy_install enum34-1.1.6-py2.7.egg
```

I am receiving invalid syntax errors. Now I'm not sure where to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pip package name is `enum34`, as in the enum module from Python 3.4.

In order to enable a single Python 2/3 code base, the actual package name is just `enum`.

So you want to `import enum` or `from enum import Enum`.

`enum` is the package, `Enum` is the class to inherit from.

So either:

```
import enum

class RGB(enum.Enum):
    Red = 1
    Green = 2
    Blue = 3
```

or

```
from enum import Enum

class RGB(Enum):
    Red = 1
    Green = 2
    Blue = 3
```